# What might "automatically install security updates" change on a server?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

On installation, an available option is to automatically install security updates - what kinds of thing might this change? Might my kernel automatically be upgraded without my input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What might “automatically install security updates” change on a server?

Any package that is in a repository that ends in `-security`. Unattended updates are logged at `/var/log/unattended-upgrades` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` is used for the configuration of unattended upgrades.

> -security includes only updated packages that contain security-related fixes, and are built to not require anything from "-updates". Anything built for "-security" is built on top of which ever version of a package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that nothing in "-security" will introduce bug regressions.

---

> Might my kernel automatically be upgraded without my input?

Kernels are added to the system so you keep the old kernel and a new one is added (where you can pick at grub what kernel needs to be loaded). You will not get a major point release kernel through security updates. Only minors.